# Highlight all rows where column Y contains X

Tags: excel, row, highlight

I have a excel worksheet with info from Column A (First name), Column B (Last name) and so on, Column G (E-mail Adresses)

I'd like to highlight all rows that has a e-mail adress from specific provider and ctrl + x them to another excel sheet.

Basically: Highlight all rows where column Y contains X

Answer (score 0):

Add another column with formula like `=ISNUMBER(FIND("some_text",A2))`. It will contain True when A2 contains 'some_text'. Then you can use Filter or Sort functions to select the rows you want.

Comment: Hey Yu_Sha. I am thankful for your answer. I tried doing this and added the formula to the new column M and it didn't work. I also tried highlight the whole column G and add the formula there, and highlight the whole sheet. I also tried Google how to add the formula, but couldn't find it. Would you give me, an excel newbie, some detailed info of where to enter formula?

Comment: You go to some cell and start typing. When you type '=', Excel will display hints that help you enter formula.

However, if you just copy and paste my formula (including = sign) to a cell it will work. Then you can copy it down to other cells of the same column. 

If you work in Excel, you must learn to enter formulas. Look for an Excel tutorial.